# Why S=1, R=1 Is forbidden in RS-Flip Flop

Tags: logic, circuits, sequential-circuit

I have come across about RS Flip Flop & I have tried implementing that on a simulator & using actual logic gates. But I'm still not sure whether I have correctly understood the case unstable or the forbidden case S=1, R=1 in Flip flop. Can anyone tell me what exactly is that?

By the way I have used 2-INPUT NAND Gates to implement the flip Flop. What is the difference between the NAND Gate Flip Flop & NOR Gate Flip Flop, ?

Comment: Hello and Welcome, your question fits better in [electronics.SE] please ask there, and you'll get better answers. Thanks!  (MODS - flag to migrate?)

Comment: Also, check the already-answered SR-FF questions they have there, like [this one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61530/how-to-understand-the-sr-latch/) and [that one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57553/sr-latch-flip-flop-beginning-inputs).

Comment: @RanG. [Is this question really off-topic here?](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/616/logical-circuits)

Comment: @Gilles, yes, I believe so.. We need to draw a line, and this, IMHO, is a clear hardware, EE, signal-level issue. Let's continue in meta.

Comment: Besides the question whether this is ontopic, the question can be improved in terms of clarity in presentation, both in terms of language and what the actual question is.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted and answered on EE.SE: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62501/why-is-s-1-r-1-state-forbidden-in-rs-flip-flop and the first question Gilles mentioned is on CS.SE, too: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/how-to-understand-the-sr-latch. This makes this one here a duplicate.

Comment: @frafl Since we can't mark questions as duplicates across sites, I added a reference to the answer as CW so we can have this question dealt with appropriately.

Comment: But this one is an **internal** duplicate too, I think.

Comment: So why are we not closing this one?

Comment: @RanG. I'm closing it, not because I think it's off-topic (I don't, and the meta discussion tends towards its being on-topic), but as a multipost that has been answered on another site.

Comment: shoud i delete this post???

Answer (score 0):

This question has an [accepted answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/62507) on another site.

Digest: If you had both inputs set to $1$, both outputs would be $0$ but they are supposed to be complementary.